# Find Distribution list(outlook DL) owner in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need help to find Distribution list(outlook DL group) owner using c#,
is there any way to get DL owner by providing DL name using outlook library or any other plugin??

help me out , thanks